# Calculate column from a specific value from another column in Spotfire

Tags: spotfire

I'm having trouble with calculating the "Age of a Week" with the current week. I don't want to use the Week() expression, because my data uses other weeknumbers than Spotfire (changing region & location is not an option). Each day my data table refreshes so my calculated column [Age_of_Day] calculates the age of the days from the current (real) date. Now I want to calculate the age of the weeks from the real week. I have a sample of my data here:

```
RowID  Week  Day  Date       Age_of_Day
12     20    do   17-5-2018   8
13     20    vr   18-5-2018   7
14     20    za   19-5-2018   6
15     21    zo   20-5-2018   5
16     21    ma   21-5-2018   4
17     21    di   22-5-2018   3
18     21    wo   23-5-2018   2
19     21    do   24-5-2018   1
20     21    vr   25-5-2018   0
21     21    za   26-5-2018  -1
22     22    zo   27-5-2018  -2
23     22    ma   28-5-2018  -3
24     22    di   29-5-2018  -4
25     22    wo   30-5-2018  -5
26     22    do   31-5-2018  -6
27     22    vr   1-6-2018   -7
```

Now I want a new column [Age_of_Week] which calculates the difference for every row between the value of [Week] and the value of [Week] when [Age_of_Day]=0. It should be something like this:

```
RowID  Week  Day  Date       Age_of_Day Age_of_Week
12     20    do   17-5-2018   8          1
13     20    vr   18-5-2018   7          1
14     20    za   19-5-2018   6          1
15     21    zo   20-5-2018   5          0
16     21    ma   21-5-2018   4          0
17     21    di   22-5-2018   3          0
18     21    wo   23-5-2018   2          0
19     21    do   24-5-2018   1          0
20     21    vr   25-5-2018   0          0
21     21    za   26-5-2018  -1          0
22     22    zo   27-5-2018  -2         -1
23     22    ma   28-5-2018  -3         -1
24     22    di   29-5-2018  -4         -1
25     22    wo   30-5-2018  -5         -1
26     22    do   31-5-2018  -6         -1
27     22    vr   1-6-2018   -7         -1
```

Hopefully, someone can help me. I think I have to use the OVER() statement and Intersect() but I don't know how in this case. Unfortunately, I couldn't find my answer with the help of other topics.

Comment: Would it work if Age_of_Week were equal to `Floor([Age_of_Day]/7+0.15)`?

Comment: Thanks, but this wouldn't work. For instance: if it is a Wednesday, the following days till Saturday are considered as week -1, instead of what i need is week 0.

Comment: which version of spotfire are you using?

Comment: @Monte_fisto: I'm using Spotfire 7.12.0.59

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From version 7 onward, you can use nested aggregations, so this expression should work.

```
First(case  when [Age_of_Day]=0 then [Week] end) - [Week]
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a nice and clean expression which works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

I've found the answer and is fairly simple. The expression for [Age_of_Week] is now:

```
If([Age of Day]>=0,Max([Week]) - [Week],If([Age of Day]<0,Min([Week]) - [Week],NULL))
```

This only works properly if the weeknumbers keep continuing (as in my case) and not reset from 52 to 1. Otherwise, something with Year() need to be added in the expression.